# Is there a fix to prevent edited text from being blurry in wallpaper?

Tags: windows, images

I edited the text to an image in paint 3D in Windows 10 and saved it as png and when I set it as desktop background and set the option in settings 'span'. But the text appears blurry but the image is fine. I cropped the section of the image which appears and also changed its resolution but the text is still blurry.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get rasterised text* as sharp as possible is to make your original image at the same resolution as your desktop - 1920x1080; 2560x1440 etc

No amount of enlarging, or crop & zoom will regain sharpness lost by stretching a smaller image.
There are apps that will do enlarging by some quite sophisticated AI these days, but even if you use one, you would do best to use it on your original image, then add the text once it's at the correct size for your screen.

(Note that at no time does DPI [dots per inch] ever come into play - DPI confuses people for some reason. For this exercise, you can totally ignore it. It's actual pixels you're counting, not DPI]

*Rasterised text is made of simple individual dots, not vector-based mathematically-derived points & lines.

Comment: Raterised -> made to be part of a bitmap, files names *.bmp, *.png, *.pcx, *.jpg all count.